# Sending a SMS in a Progressive Web App Doesn't Always Work on iPhone

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, progressive-web-apps

I have made a progressive web app. One part of it should update a mysql database and prepare to send a SMS. It seems to work well on Android but is erratic on iPhone. When it goes wrong, the iPhone shows "sms:+4412345678?&body=1" in the browser address bar instead of opening the SMS app.

The html is

```
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=1"><button class="1">Going to RV</button></a>
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=2"><button class="2">Going to Station</button></a>
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=3"><button class="3">Delayed but Attending</button></a>
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=4"><button class="4">On Scene</button></a>
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=5"><button class="5">Not Attending</button></a>
```

Then I have a Jquery function

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var callsign = "<?php echo $callsign ?>";
        var response = $(this).attr("class");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myresponse.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {callsign: callsign,
                response: response}
        }).done(function() {
                $("#beforeresponse").css("display", "none");
                $("#tresponse").css("display", "block");
                $("#teamresponse").load("allresponses.php div#teamresponse");
            });
    });
});
```

I think perhaps the two tasks are tripping over each other and causing a problem depending on which starts or finishes first. Does that sound feasible?

I am wondering whether I can disable the links

```
<a href="sms:+4412345678?&body=1" disabled="disabled"><button class="1">Going to RV</button></a>
```

and then trigger the SMS with a .done function after the existing .done is completed. If so, how?

Or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally worked out the answer. I hope this may be of use to someone else.

The link "sms:+4412345678?&body=1" works when the page is opened in a browser window, but not when it is installed as a web app. So for this particular app where the SMS message is a fundamental part of the functionality, I have to steer iPhone users to just place a shortcut on their home page, while Android users can install the app in the normal proper way.

It feels a bit hacky, but it's a solution.